# How can I make a checkbox list in a telegram bot?

Tags: c#, telegram

I´m developing a telegram bot in c#. 
Using the class `TelegramBotClient` in `Telegram.Bot` library.

I want to create a list with multiple option choose using a `InlineKeyboardButton`.

I am thinking in some kind of `CheckListBox` as in `Window Form`.

Someone knows how to do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yo can make buttons and add to them ✓ in text if it checked.
Look at bsab [answer](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/issues/307#issuecomment-351340973)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved my problem, I use this method: ```await Bot.EditMessageReplyMarkupAsync(
                                chatId: callbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id,
                                messageId: callbackQuery.Message.MessageId,
                                replyMarkup: new InlineKeyboardMarkup(botonesTL));```

Answer (score -3):

If you're using WinForms then you should look at CheckBoxList - it's one of the standard controls.

If you're using WPF there's a control called CheckBoxList that is practically the same thing.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I didn´t explain as good as I thought. In fact, I want to simulate a CheckBoxList but in Telegram Bot inteface. Thank you anyway for the answare.